# is Ajax a viable option to create a tick-able tasklist?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am in the process of creating a tasklist for my site. users will be able to add new tasks related to a project with a simple text entry form with a datepicker.

The tasks are displayed in a simple list with a checkbox next to them. My intention is to have this so when a box is ticked, the text gets a line through it and the sql table is updated. ( no actual save button).

Never having used Ajax before I wanted to know if the method I intended to use below is the right way to approach this problem or if their is a better option I should consider. I am a relative beginner who is learning as I work on the project.

My intention was to have a click event that called a jquery function on each of the checkboxes (a different one for check / uncheck?), it would pass the id number of the task which the jquery fills into a dummy form and posts it via ajax to a php file that will update the sql table.

Having never used ajax, would this even be possible. Would their be a performance issue? i.e what happens if you click lots of boxes. (This is an internal site that would at max have 2 or 3 people using it simultaneously, but infrequently).

I have test some Ajax form submission using the form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
but one thing I do not understand is how to take some action once it is done, for example how do I refresh the list so it shows the updated information from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a legit way to solve your problem. You don't really need a dummy form.

You could make your function like this:

```
function checkboxChecked(id)
{
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "yourPhpPage.php",
      data: { action: "checked", 
              id: id }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
         console.log("succeeded")
    }
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

}
```

Source: [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

This shouldn't give you any performance issues, except if you suspect a lot of clicks per second.

For the server-side, you can use this code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['action'], $_POST['id']))
    return;

if ($_POST['action'] == "checked") {
   // your SQL call here.. Watch out for sql-injection!
}
else if ($_POST['action'] == "unchecked") {
   // your SQL call here.. Watch out for sql-injection!
}
```

Comment: Hi, i seem to get an error along the lines of     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;    I realised that there is a bracket missing in the ajax call. Not sure exactly where it should go though. ( after the .done(function... line , it is not closed off i believe. could you help?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: with the checkboxChecked() function, the console gives an error related to a semi colon on loading, and then a function not defined error when i try and call it. I am not totally sure how the .done & .fail work so copied them exactly as you suggested for now - I believe there is a close bracket ")" that is missing and should go after the"{ console.log("suceeded") }" but that didn't seem to work either.EDIT: SORRY IGNORE ME, infact that bracket did fix it. MANY THANKS AGAIN

Comment: No problem, I actually didn't check my own code, just wrote it here in the post. :) Should have checked it myself first. Good luck with your project!